# Prove that if $n$ is a perfect number, $kn$ is not

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Prove that if $n$ is a perfect number, $kn$ is not.

---

If $\gcd(k,n)=1$ then  this is clear.

(assume $\sigma(n)=2n$ , $\sigma(nk)=2kn$ , then $k=\sigma(k)$ but $\sigma(k)>k)$.

But what about $\gcd(k,n)>1$?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Find some proper divisors of $kn$ that add up to exactly $kn$.  Are any divisors missing?

Comment: sigma(kn)= kn + k +n+..  ?

Comment: @user1932595 Look at an example, like how $6 = 1 + 2 + 3$ is perfect and $12 = 2 + 4 + 6$ is not

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1,...a_r$ be the divisors of $n$, we know that $\sum a_i  = n$. So $kn$ is divisible by $ka_1,...,ka_n$ which sum to $kn$ but also by $a_1$ so the sum of the divisors of $kn$ is greater than $kn$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$, then
$$y \mid z \implies I(y) \leq I(z),$$
with equality if $y = z$.

Can you take it from here?